# Playing a sound with AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avaudioplayer

I'm trying to play a sound with `AVAudioPlayer` but it won't work.

**Edit 1:** Still doesn't work.

**Edit 2**: This code works. My device was in silent mode.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var alertSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("button-09", ofType: "wav"))
        println(alertSound)

        var error:NSError?
        audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: alertSound, error: &error)
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer.play()
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of passing "`nil`" to the error parameter, why not pass something in and find out what the error actually is?

Comment: the error contains nil

Comment: I'm practically using the exact same code as you for an osx application, and it all works except for the error code seems to be throwing some type of error itself: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" which leads me to believe that there is something wrong with the error declaration. I don't know a lot about error in swift, but is this something you've run into before?

Comment: @Uzebeckatrente - Check that you are not using NSURL(string:...). This returns nil for some reason in some circumstances. You should be using NSURL(fileURLWithPath:...) for file locations.

Comment: @djb it's the NSError that's giving me issues, rather than the NSURL, I believe.

Comment: hahaha... kudos for silent mode!

Comment: @djb NSURL(string:) it is for web resources only (web links) and NSURL(fileURLWithPath:) it is for local resource files (documents folder)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Made modification to your code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var alertSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("button-09", ofType: "wav"))
        println(alertSound)

        // Removed deprecated use of AVAudioSessionDelegate protocol
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil)
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)

        var error:NSError?
        audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: alertSound, error: &error)
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer.play()
    }

}
```

**Swift 3 and Swift 4.1:**

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let alertSound = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "button-09", ofType: "wav")!)
        print(alertSound)

        try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

        try! audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: alertSound)
        audioPlayer!.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer!.play()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to add sound to my program using about the same code and it is crashing. Where exactly do u put the audio file? In the assets folder or..?

Comment: @skyguy, you may drag the sound file to your project and select the proper target to add.

Comment: any ideas on how to use it for pls or remote mp3 files?

Comment: @edse for remote mp3 file, initialize your alertSound like `var alertSound = NSURL(string: "http://my-file-url.com/song.mp3")`

Comment: Will this work for streaming? I was trying the following with a pls ulr http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26075618/swift-radio-streaming-avplayer

Comment: I just tried this with a remote mp3 file and a pls file but it doesn't play any sound. If I use a local file works perfectly.

Comment: "The AVplayer doesn't provide support for streaming, you can with AVPlayer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635792/play-audio-from-internet-using-avaudioplayer

Comment: Do I have to create a new instance of ``AVAudioPlayer`` for each sound file I will play?

Comment: Anyone else with some weird issue as mine, "just not working after copy pasting the code, ensure proper location and import of your files in the build phase" and the code above should thereafter work

Answer (score 36):

As per Swift 2 the code should be

```
var audioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer!

func playSound(soundName: String)
{
    let coinSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(soundName, ofType: "m4a")!)
    do{
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL:coinSound)
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()//there is also an async version
        audioPlayer.play()
    }catch {
        print("Error getting the audio file")
    }
}
```

Comment: You should make audioPlayer an instance variable somewhere. This code will have it deallocated immediately after calling .play() and you won't hear a thing.

Comment: The app will also experience a slight lag because it needs to load the file and prepare the player all at once.

Answer (score 23):

Your audio play will be deallocated right after viewDidLoad finishes since you assign it to a local variable. You need to create a property for it to keep it around.

Comment: @Alexsander This is how: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24393495/playing-a-sound-with-avaudioplayer#29788123

Answer (score 12):

The solution is for AudioPlayer which has play/pause/stop button in the navigation bar as bar button items

In Swift 2.1 you can use the below code

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var player:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            let audioPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("ARRehman", ofType: "mp3")
            var error:NSError? = nil
            do {
                player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!))
            }
            catch {
                print("Something bad happened. Try catching specific errors to narrow things down")
            }

        }

    @IBAction func play(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        player.play()

    }


    @IBAction func stop(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        player.stop()
        print(player.currentTime)
        player.currentTime = 0
    }


    @IBAction func pause(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        player.pause()
    }


    @IBOutlet weak var sliderval: UISlider!


    @IBAction func slidermov(sender: UISlider) {

        player.volume = sliderval.value
        print(player.volume)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7):

This will work.....

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var ding:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        prepareAudios()
        ding.play()
    }

    func prepareAudios() {

        var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("ding", ofType: "mp3")
        ding = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!), error: nil)
        ding.prepareToPlay()
    }
}
```

Comment: _"This will work"_ But why it will work? Please explain what's wrong with OP and how you resolved it so that future users can understand the concept behind it.

Answer (score 2):

Use This Function to make sound in Swift (You can use this function where you want to make sound.)

First Add SpriteKit and AVFoundation Framework.

```
import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation
func playEffectSound(filename: String){
     runAction(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("\(filename)", waitForCompletion: false))
}// use this function to play sound

playEffectSound("Sound File Name With Extension")
// Example :- playEffectSound("BS_SpiderWeb_CollectEgg_SFX.mp3")
```

Comment: This may "work", but it does not preload audio and my result in negative performance when first executed

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty old question, but I did not see an answer that worked with Swift 3.0 so I modernized the code and added some safety checks to prevent crashes.

I also took the approach of pulling the playing part out into its own function to help with re-use for anyone coming across this answer.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        play(for: "button-09", type: "wav")
    }

    func play(for resource: String, type: String) {
        // Prevent a crash in the event that the resource or type is invalid
        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: resource, ofType: type) else { return }
        // Convert path to URL for audio player
        let sound = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: sound)
            audioPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
            audioPlayer?.play()
        } catch {
            // Create an assertion crash in the event that the app fails to play the sound
            assert(false, error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: make audioPlayer an instance variable

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4.2 onwards, AudioSession category setup options have been changed. (Try following code for Swift 4.2 onwards)

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation


class ViewController: UIViewController {


    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        prepareAudioSession()
    }


    func prepareAudioSession() -> Void {
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback, mode: AVAudioSession.Mode.default, options: AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions.defaultToSpeaker)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

            prepareAudioPlayer()

        } catch {
            print("Issue with Audio Session")
        }
    }


    func prepareAudioPlayer() -> Void {

        let audioFileName = "test"
        let audioFileExtension = "mp3"

        guard let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: audioFileName, ofType: audioFileExtension) else {
            print("Audio file not found at specified path")
            return
        }

        let alertSound = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
        try? audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: alertSound)
        audioPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
    }


    func playAudioPlayer() -> Void {
        audioPlayer?.play()
    }


    func pauseAudioPlayer() -> Void {
        if audioPlayer?.isPlaying ?? false {
            audioPlayer?.pause()
        }
    }


    func stopAudioPlayer() -> Void {
        if audioPlayer?.isPlaying ?? false {
            audioPlayer?.stop()
        }
    }

    func resetAudioPlayer() -> Void {
        stopAudioPlayer()
        audioPlayer?.currentTime = 0
        playAudioPlayer()
    }

}
```

Comment: I got error in prepareAudioSession function... did you face this issue in iOS 12.