# Swift Radio Streaming AVPlayer

Tags: swift, avplayer, audio-streaming, internet-radio

I want to stream an audio from the Internet in Swift but haven't found a correct functional example just yet.

In **Objective-C**

```
AVPlayerItem* playerItem =[AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:streamURL]];
[playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"timedMetadata" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
music = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
[music play];
```

What Im trying in **Swift**

```
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL:NSURL(string:url))
        var player:AVPlayer!
        player = AVPlayer(playerItem:playerItem)
        player.rate = 1.0;
        player.play()
//this is not working
```

I also tried adding playerItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "timedMetadata", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil) but I got an error

'An instance 0x16edbd20 of class AVPlayerItem was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Current observation info:  (
 Context: 0x0, Property: 0x16ea5880>
)'

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Have you consider using AVAudioPlayer?

Comment: Are you sure the `playerItem` is alive after the play command? Quick thing to try is to add a `sleep(10)` after the play command. This will keep the thread alive for ten seconds. If you get lucky there might be some sound then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a radio player with swift, but i used **MediaPlayer** framework to play.

```
var radioPlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: "YOUR NSURL OBJECT WITH YOUR CUSTOM URL TO STREAM HERE");
radioPlayer.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
radioPlayer.view.sizeToFit()
radioPlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceType.Streaming
radioPlayer.fullscreen = false;
radioPlayer.shouldAutoplay = true;
radioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
radioPlayer.play()
radioPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.None;
```

If you need listen metada from stream you need observer this notification **MPMoviePlayerTimedMetadataUpdatedNotification**

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("metadataUpdated:"), name:MPMoviePlayerTimedMetadataUpdatedNotification, object: nil);

func metadataUpdated(n:NSNotification)
{
    if(radioPlayer.timedMetadata != nil && radioPlayer.timedMetadata.count > 0)
    {
        let firstMeta:MPTimedMetadata = radioPlayer.timedMetadata.first as! MPTimedMetadata;
        let data:String = firstMeta.value as! String;
        println(data); //your metadata here
    }
}
```

With this you will can make your radio player, and because this radio i worked, i made one lib to get information about music in Itunes, well, this lib is open and because this I just want one favor, if you find problem, bug our better solution, fix and push to all.

[ItunesSearch Lib in GitHub](https://github.com/Tavernari/itunes-search)