# Need help adding an audio file to a button in swift

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6

can anyone help me get this to work I am a noob programer and I could not find a way to do this.

Code below

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func pistolButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() { // I want my audio file to play when button is tapped
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your code to make some kind of sense, an overabundance of white space and empty functions do not a good question make.  See the Help Center for guidance on asking good questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First drag your sound to your project and choose to copy for your destination if needed and check "add to target" to your app. Create a function to play your sound and you need also to add import AVFoundation at the beginning of your code as bellow:

```
import AVFoundation

let beepSoundURL =  NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("beep", withExtension: "aif")!
var beepPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
func playMySound(){
   beepPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: beepSoundURL, error: nil)
   beepPlayer.prepareToPlay()
   beepPlayer.play()
}

@IBAction func pistolButton(sender: AnyObject) {
   playMySound()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a lot of pretty good code on Stack Overflow:

[Playing a sound with AVAudioPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24393495/playing-a-sound-with-avaudioplayer-swift)

Here is some example code:

```
import AVFoundation
var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?

if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("mysound", ofType: "aiff") {
    audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path), fileTypeHint: "aiff", error: nil)

    if let sound = audioPlayer {
        sound.prepareToPlay()
        sound.play()
    }
}
```

from this location:

http://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/28izxl/how_do_you_play_a_sound_in_ios/

Answer (score -1):

**Swift 3**

the syntax is now as follows:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // address of the music file
        let music = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Music", ofType: "mp3")

        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: music! ))
        }
        catch{
            print(error)
        }   
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    @IBAction func play(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        audioPlayer.play()   
    }
    @IBAction func stop(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        audioPlayer.stop()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Swift 5.5 version syntax.`

```swift
import AVFoundation

let beepSoundURL =  Bundle.main.url(forResource: "gosound", withExtension: "wav")
var beepPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

func playMySound(){
   if let soundGo = beepSoundURL {
       do {
          try beepPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundGo, fileTypeHint: nil)
           }
       catch {
            print ("error")
           } 
        }
       beepPlayer.prepareToPlay()
       beepPlayer.play()
}

@IBAction func pistolButton(sender: AnyObject) {
   playMySound()
}
```