# Adding sound effects in Spritekit

Tags: ios, swift, audio, sprite-kit

I'm making a Flappy Bird-type game, and I want to add a sound effect for when a coin is collected. This is what I have:

```
import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var coinSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Super Mario Bros.- Coin Sound Effect", ofType: "mp3")!)
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
```

Later in my didMoveToView:

```
audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: coinSound, error: nil)
audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
```

For the second part (in my didMoveToView), the first line keeps showing an error:

> Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled

How do I fix this?

Comment: have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24393495/playing-a-sound-with-avaudioplayer

Comment: does this, when corrected by the answer, actually play a sound?

Comment: I know you already marked an answer but I would actually use SKAction.playSound... for short 1 time sounds. AVFoundation is better used for background music.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: coinSound, error: nil)
> ```

This is no longer the way that errors are handled in Swift.  You must use the do-try-catch syntax.

```
do {
    audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: coinSound)
    audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
}
catch let error {
    // handle error
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't care to write any error handling code, you can make your `audioPlayer` variable optional and write a failable `try?`:

```
audioPlayer = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: coinSound)
audioPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
```

This is more closely equivalent to the code you're attempting where you pass `nil` for the error parameter.

Or if crashing is the appropriate behavior when an error occurs, you could take this approach:

```
guard let audioPlayer = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: coinSound) else {
    fatalError("Failed to initialize the audio player with asset: \(coinSound)")
}
audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
self.audioPlayer = audioPlayer
```

Comment: If you get a moment, and are inclined, could you answer the question in my comment in the swift 3 version below?

Comment: An alternative for immediate crashing is `let audioPlayer = try! etc...`. You don't get the detailed error message, but if you're debugging then Xcode will pinpoint the location anyway.

Answer (score 15):

I know you already have marked an answer but if you re read this question or for future readers its easier to use SKActions to play a short 1 time sound.

AVFoundation is better used for background music.

e.g

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

     // add as class property so sound is preloaded and always ready
     let coinSound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("NAMEOFSOUNDFILE", waitForCompletion: false)
}
```

and than when you need to play the sound simply say this

```
run(coinSound)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm using this way, now. It's a SHIT TONNE easier, and if the action is precreated, seems to be caching the audio file so there's no loading/lag on the first play.

Comment: Yeah it is. I did not actually realise this was a 7 month old question, thought it was new.

Answer (score 0):

### Swift 3.0+

For the above `guard let` example from @nhgrif, this Swift 3.0+ way of doing it:

```
var coinSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Super Mario Bros.- Coin Sound Effect", ofType: "mp3")!)
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

func playCoinSound(){
    guard let soundToPlay = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: coinSound as URL) else {
        fatalError("Failed to initialize the audio player with asset: \(coinSound)")
    }
    soundToPlay.prepareToPlay()

//  soundToPlay.play() // NO IDEA WHY THIS DOES NOT WORK!!!???

    self.audioPlayer = soundToPlay
    self.audioPlayer.play() // But this does work... please let me know why???
}

playCoinSound()
```

Comment: I have no idea. I just copied that from all the other guards I have in my (increasingly massive) reference files. Which was from above, the answer by nhgrif. I hadn't used it until today, at which point I found out about the swift 3 changes, and got curious about the need to repeat myself to get it to play.

Comment: Thats cool just asking. Probably better to use return in this case and exit gracefully so your app doesn't crash.