# Is there a ready made audio player in Xcode similar to the ones used in music, podcast, and telegram apps?

Tags: ios, xcode, audio, audio-player

I'm new to Swift and I don't know Objective C. I am looking forward to design a standard audio player. I've noticed that music, podcast, and telegram apps use kind of the same player. I don't know how to add that player in my app. Did they design it from scratch or is there a ready made player bar that can be added in my app?

I've downloaded the source of telegram app, but it is big, in objective C, and doesn't compile!

So, how to get that player?

[image: music app player]
[image: telegram player]

Comment: Maybe you could try this free course - https://www.udemy.com/make-media-player-app-for-ios-8-using-swift-avfoundation/

Comment: @SimonBosley I've done something similar before, but the player has few issues. e.g. It doesn't show in the media control buttons on the lock screen, music is muted if the ringer is on mute, and I have to manually program the showing and hiding of play and pause buttons. I was looking for something ready-made that handle all of those issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out [LNPopupController](https://github.com/LeoNatan/LNPopupController), is a framework for presenting view controllers as popups of other view controllers, much like the Apple Music and Podcasts apps.

It has Demo Music Scene in both **Objective-C** & **Swift**

*Note: this is the UI/UX of the player not the actual player so it doesn't inluclude any `AVAudioPlayer`. To build your player you could have a look to this: [Playing a sound with AVAudioPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24393495/playing-a-sound-with-avaudioplayer)*

Answer (score 0):

LNPopupController is just great, but if you want to keep your own controls on the toolbar, create your own. For reference:[here](https://github.com/xxxAIRINxxx/MusicPlayerTransition)