# Playing different sounds in TableView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, audio, avfoundation

[image: First, this is how my app looks like]

Now I want to play different sounds when I click buttons inside these table view cells. I am very new at programming and I couldn't figure out how to do this. I have created an array for my sound files but I don't know how to assign them to those buttons in a row. Thank you very much for your help

AND THIS IS MY CODE

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController6: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


//Array of Rifles

    var arrayOfRifles = ["AK47", "AUGA1", "FAMAS", "G36K", "K1A", "K2", "M4A1", "M4Silencer", "M16", "M60", "MicroGALIL", "QBZ95", "RPK", "ScarHeavy", "Scarlight", "SG552", "TAR21", "Tommy", "Type89", "XM8"]
    var buttonDataRifles = ["AK47", "AUGA1", "FAMAS", "G36K", "K1A", "K2", "M4A1", "M4Silencer", "M16", "M60", "MicroGALIL", "QBZ95", "RPK", "ScarHeavy", "Scarlight", "SG552", "TAR21", "Tommy", "Type89", "XM8"]

    var soundsArray: [NSURL] = [
    NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "AK47", ofType: "mp3")!),
    NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "AUGA1", ofType: "mp3")!),
    NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "FAMAS", ofType: "mp3")!),
    NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "G36K", ofType: "mp3")!),
    NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "K1A", ofType: "mp3")!),
    NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "K2", ofType: "mp3")!),
    NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "M4A1", ofType: "mp3")!),
    NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "M4Silencer", ofType: "mp3")!),
    NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "M16", ofType: "mp3")!),
    NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "M60", ofType: "mp3")!),
    NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "MicroGALIL", ofType: "mp3")!),
    NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "QBZ95", ofType: "mp3")!),
    NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "RPK", ofType: "mp3")!),
    NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ScarHeavy", ofType: "mp3")!),
    NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ScarLight", ofType: "mp3")!),
    NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "SG552", ofType: "mp3")!),
    NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "TAR21", ofType: "mp3")!),
    NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Tommy", ofType: "mp3")!),
    NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Type89", ofType: "mp3")!),
    NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "XM8", ofType: "mp3")!)
    ]




//Functions for tableView

    //Cell - For Rifles

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return (arrayOfRifles.count)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell6 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell6", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell6

        cell6.myImage.image = UIImage(named: arrayOfRifles[indexPath.row] + ".jpg")
        cell6.myButton.setTitle(buttonDataRifles[indexPath.row], for: UIControlState.normal)
        return (cell6)

        cell6.myButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell6.myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)}

    @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

        print("Button tapped")
        let tapedIndex = sender as UIButton
        let getUrl = soundsArray[tapedIndex] as! NSURL


    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to add action to button and assign some tag to that button to identify which one is clicked.do some code on cellForRowAt

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

cell6.myButton.tag = indexPath.row
cell6.myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)}

func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) 
{ 
print("Button tapped")
let tapedIndex = sender as! UIButton
let getUrl = buttonDataRifles[tapedIndex.tag] as! NSURL 
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'assign some tag to that button to identify which one is clicked'?

Comment: We have to assign here cell6.myButton.tag =  indexPath.row as tag so whenever we click on only row of button, so we can identify which button click on basis we can play song of that row.

Comment: let getUrl = soundsArray[tapedIndex] as! NSURL
I got an error in this line that says 'Cannot subscript a value of type 'NSURL'  with an index of type 'UIButton'

Comment: Can you share your code me ? so i can get more idea.

Comment: I have just made one change "let getUrl = buttonDataRifles[tapedIndex.tag] as! NSURL"

Comment: I have updated my first message and added my code. Thanks

Comment: Yes but now when i 'return (cell6)' i get an error that says Expected declaration'

Comment: i think you have return cell by end of method

Comment: do like return cell6 instead of return (cell6)

Comment: Nothing changed. Still same error. Man!! This is annoying

Comment: you are missing cell6!

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: trying to return like "return cell6! " or  return cell6 as! UITableViewCell "

Comment: Fixed it!! .touchUpInside)} there is a curly bracket here and we didnt see it :) Now what should i do next? I am not sure

Comment: well sorry for being a pain in the ass but i didn't understand what you mean

Comment: explain here what do want to do next ?

Comment: I want my buttons in my cells to play my audio files. For example first button in the first cell plays first audio file in my soundsArray, second button in the second cell plays second audio file in my soundsArray etc

Comment: if you dont know how play audio then please refer this answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24393495/playing-a-sound-with-avaudioplayer

if you still not clear let me know

Answer (score 0):

If u'r sounds not more that 30 sec I suggest to use `AudioToolbox`. This framework has specially designed functionality for such purpose.

**Objective-C**

1. import framework

   ```
   #import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
   ```
2. make reference for your sound with creating `SystemSoundID` like

   ```
   @property (assign, nonatomic) SystemSoundID soundIDOne;
   ```
3. Prepare you'r sonds in the very begginning

   ```
   AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID ( (__bridge CFURLRef)([[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Swish" ofType:@"wav"]]), &_soundIDDone);
   ```
4. Play sound

   ```
   AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(_soundIDOne);
   ```
5. If u need completion - add handler

   ```
   AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion(_soundIDOne, NULL, NULL, playSoundFinished, NULL);


   void playSoundFinished (SystemSoundID sound, void *data) {
       //do stuff here
   }
   ```

**Swift 2.2**

```
    import AudioToolbox

    private var soundID:SystemSoundID?

    if let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("name", ofType: "type") {
        let pathToResource = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
        soundID = 0
        if var soundID = soundID {
            AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(pathToResource, &soundID)
        }
    }

    if var soundID = soundID {
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID)
    }

    //or create extension

    extension SystemSoundID {
        static func playSound(soundName: String, fileExtension: String) {
            var soundID: SystemSoundID = 0
            if let filePath =  NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(soundName, ofType: fileExtension) {
                let pathToResource = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
                AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(pathToResource, &soundID)
                AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID)
            }
        }
    }

    //and usage

    SystemSoundID.playSound("soundFileName", fileExtension: "extension")
```

For more look [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/audiotoolbox/1657326-system_sound_services)

In case u want to use AVFoundation instead code will be like:

```
    import AVFoundation

    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer() //create player

    //create all path to y'r resources

    var path:[NSURL] = []

    if let filePath =  NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("soundName", ofType: "fileExtension") {
        let pathToResource = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
        path.append(pathToResource)
    }

    //in the very start
    do {
        if let selectedPath = path.first {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: selectedPath)
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

    audioPlayer.play()
```

In this case, u can get some delay before sound playing because of required `prepareToPlay` for AVAudioPlayer, to be sure that u can play sound u need a little bit more complex setup of AVPlayer with observation for `status` of player, if u like u can refer to [this link](https://developer.apple.com/av-foundation/). Also, if u have files with short duration this delay can be very small or even absent, anyway, as for me this is not preferred way to play a lot of sound files due to reason described above

And of cause I cant tell u about `AVFoundationQueuePlayer`, this is also good solution. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVFoundationQueuePlayer-iOS/Introduction/Intro.html) is Apple Sample link