# Objective-C: Making AVPlayer plays in all the app controllers (or in the background)

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

I'm making a news iOS app, i want to implement a live audio streaming in all the pages like the picture below:

[image: App Screenshot]

The orange view is a UIView that says "Live Streaming" (in Arabic), it exists in all the viewControllers, i want to let the AVPlayer plays when the user clicks on it and still plays even if the user navigates to other viewControllers.

I can't seem to find a good solution or tutorial about this, sorry if this is a noob question cause i'm new to iOS.

So how can i do that ? and where(in which viewController) should i put the AVPlayer declaration ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would probably try using NSUserDefaults to store the users selection, and have each view check whether anything has been selected and if so to play it.

Comment: @SaSmith and how can i keep the AVPlayer playing, i think through the audio session, i tried it and didn't work

Comment: To be honest, I am not too sure. I wouldn't think it should be dismissing the AVPlayer when switching views though, not unless you have coded that somewhere, that AVPlayer should stop playing when view is changed. The only thing I could think of is if the app is retrieving content from online it may not be allowed to keep playing in the background, but I am not 100% sure about that.

Comment: Have posted an answer, please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, i had to make a singleton class.

The singleton class allow only one object to be used in the entire iOS application by all the ViewControllers.

And i did put all the needed methods like play and pause in the singleton class and i accessed them from all the ViewControllers.

If anybody wants an example, please ask in the comments.

Comment: please , give a example with multiple Video palys On Click of forward and backword Button in AVPlayer

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing in the simulator, the change of views will not continue the audio in the background. If it is not working your device try this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: yourURLHere];    
AVURLAsset *avAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];    
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:avAsset];    
AVPlayer *audioPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];    
//This enables background music playing
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];    

[audioPlayer play];
```

Place this code in your viewDidLoad method, before `[super viewDidLoad];`

I found two links that exaplin some of the issues on this:

1. [Play Music in Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619794/play-music-in-the-background-using-avaudioplayer)
2. [Play Audio from Internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635792/play-audio-from-internet-using-avaudioplayer)

If this does not work, I would recommend placing a bounty on the question as it seems your issue's are a little more in depth than a simple solution.

Comment: Made edit as AVAudioPlayer only plays local files, you asked AVPlayer, which is for http links.

Comment: Thanks, let me try that :)

Comment: @FadiObaji did this work for you? It's the best and seemingly most reliable solution I could find.

Comment: the music plays fine, but when i click on something in the side menu to navigate to another ViewController, the stream stops

Comment: Are you testing using a device? It's a common issue using a simulator for audio to not work as desired.

Comment: Let me check on a real device

Comment: Didn't work either, but i think i have to make a Singleton Class in order for this to work, i'm gonna try that