# iOS AVPlayer No sound

Tags: ios, url, audio, avplayer

This is my code. I have checked URL. But there is no sound.

var player = AVPlayer()

```
func playAudio(sender:UIButton!){
    var btnsendtag:UIButton = sender


    let url : String = self.array_mainlist[btnsendtag.tag]["voice_url"] as String
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem( URL:NSURL( string:url ) )
    player = AVPlayer(playerItem:playerItem)
    player.rate = 1.0;
    player.play()


}
```

AND LOG
: setMessageLoggingBlock: called

Comment: Are you playing video or sound?

Comment: sound. file type is ".3gp" .

Comment: You should use `AVAudioPlayer` to play sound files.

Comment: sorry. my explanation was insufficient. url is http url. not local.

Comment: But you can play http url also from `AVAudioPlayer`

Comment: I have searched AVAudioPlayer. but AVAudioPlayer is not support http.

Comment: Please take a look at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635792/play-audio-from-internet-using-avaudioplayer

Comment: @RoyNakum read Technical Q&A QA1634
  ... AVAudioPlayer doesn't support remote url. AVPlayer is the way to go (not only does it support remote url's but it also supports HLS). If you're not sure you shouldn't post!

Answer (score 0):

An audio mix can only be used with file-based media and is not supported for use with media served using HTTP Live Streaming.

Otherwise, the audioMix property of an AVPlayerItem can be set to the value of the audioMix property returned by the requestAVAssetForVideo:options:resultHandler: method of PHImageManager.